# Jquery swap rows in table and saving the new position of rows with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a table with rows, where every row has the same class, something like this:

```
<tr class = "taskProp">
    <td class = "checkWidth" > 

        <%= check_box_tag task.name, task.status, false, class: "check" %> 

    </td>

    <td class = "textWidth"> <p class = "form-control-static textRender"> <%= task.name %> </p> </td>

    <td>
      <span>

        <%= link_to "", nil, remote: true, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-sort colorTask" %>

        <%= link_to "", edit_task_path(task), class: "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil colorTask" %>

        <%= link_to "", task, method: :delete, remote: true, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-trash colorTask" %>

      </span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have implemented the function, which can swap the rows, it looks like this:

```
swapRows = (rowTable) ->
    rowTable.find(".glyphicon-sort").click ->
        row = $(this).closest("tr")
        row.insertBefore( row.prev() )
```

It works all fine, but I need to save the state of these swaps, when the page is reloaded. I'm already using jquery cookie plugin or in my situation gem and I need an idea how can I save swapped position of rows in table. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Have you considered sessionStorage, localStorage, or do you have a server in which you can store session variables?

Comment: Well I have cookies, that do the same thing as session if that's that you meant. But I don't understand how can you store a html position in server-side.In my mind it's more obvious to use jquery to order this, but I don't know how.Maybe it'd look something like looping through all tr tag and initializing it with a cookie that contains position and then when you restart the page, the cookies gonna do the job.